# Using Part rather than Extract

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

In my work I found that I needed the `Extract` function.  However I was wondering if there was a way to use `Part`.  Assume that `mList` is a 4-dim array.

I did the following, which worked.

```
x = {2, 10, 3, 4};
y = Extract[mList, x];
```

I found that I can't do this.

```
y = mList[[x]]
```

Is there a way to convert the list `x`, into a sequence of integers that I can use in `Part`?  I tried enclosing it in `Sequence`, but that seemed to have no effect.

As I said, I'm fine without this, I was just wondering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SeedRandom@1;
myList = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {10, 10, 10, 10}];
x = {2, 10, 3, 4};
y = Extract[myList, x]
```

> ```
> 9
> ```

```
Part[myList, Sequence @@ x]
```

> ```
> 9
> ```

On a smaller list:

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
{Extract[list, {1, 1}], Part[list, Sequence @@ {1, 1}]}
```

> ```
> {a, a}
> ```

Knowing that, as [Kuba noted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50675/using-part-like-extract#comment149431_50676), `Part[list, Sequence @@ {1, 1}]` is equivalent to `list[[##]] & @@ {1, 1}`.

Answer (score 5):

Two further variations of the same theme (actually for the first one only the input syntax is different):

```
myList[[Sequence@@x]]
mylist[[##&@@x]]
```

And a different one:

```
Part@@Prepend[x,myList]
```

Comment: The first 2 in particular and very nice!  The 3rd was very instructional.

Answer (score 4):

Try this also:

```
SeedRandom@1;
myList = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {10, 10, 10, 10}];
y=myList[[Delete[x, 0]]]
```

or

```
y=myList[[x /. List -> Sequence]]
```