# Coefficients in multidimensional polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I have a multidimensional polynomial depending on `{x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4]}`.
If I want to selectively collect the coefficient corresponding to e.g.
`a*x[1]*x[2]` I write:

```
 Coefficient[polynom,x[1]*x[2]]
```

This also gives the Coefficient of `b*x[1]*x[2]x[3]` as `b*x[3]`.
I made a workaround to get only the coefficient corresponding to `a*x[1]*x[2]`.

```
 Select[Coefficient[polynom,x[1]*x[2]],AtomQ]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: It would help if you included an example for `polynom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use [`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html). Here is an example:

```
poly = 
 Sum[a[i, j, k] x[1]^i x[2]^j x[3]^k, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}, {k, 0, 2}]

(*
==> a[0, 0, 0] + a[1, 0, 0] x[1] + a[2, 0, 0] x[1]^2 + 
 a[0, 1, 0] x[2] + a[1, 1, 0] x[1] x[2] + a[2, 1, 0] x[1]^2 x[2] + 
 a[0, 2, 0] x[2]^2 + a[1, 2, 0] x[1] x[2]^2 + 
 a[2, 2, 0] x[1]^2 x[2]^2 + a[0, 0, 1] x[3] + a[1, 0, 1] x[1] x[3] + 
 a[2, 0, 1] x[1]^2 x[3] + a[0, 1, 1] x[2] x[3] + 
 a[1, 1, 1] x[1] x[2] x[3] + a[2, 1, 1] x[1]^2 x[2] x[3] + 
 a[0, 2, 1] x[2]^2 x[3] + a[1, 2, 1] x[1] x[2]^2 x[3] + 
 a[2, 2, 1] x[1]^2 x[2]^2 x[3] + a[0, 0, 2] x[3]^2 + 
 a[1, 0, 2] x[1] x[3]^2 + a[2, 0, 2] x[1]^2 x[3]^2 + 
 a[0, 1, 2] x[2] x[3]^2 + a[1, 1, 2] x[1] x[2] x[3]^2 + 
 a[2, 1, 2] x[1]^2 x[2] x[3]^2 + a[0, 2, 2] x[2]^2 x[3]^2 + 
 a[1, 2, 2] x[1] x[2]^2 x[3]^2 + a[2, 2, 2] x[1]^2 x[2]^2 x[3]^2
*)

Extract[CoefficientList[poly, Array[x, {3}]], {2, 0, 1} + 1]

(* ==> a[2, 0, 1] *)
```

This shows that the coefficient of the powers $x[1]^2x[3]$ is `a[2,0,1]`. In the `Extract` command, the powers `{2,0,1}` are turned into indices by adding `1` to all of them.

This approach is especially suitable if you want to extract more than one coefficient, because you can construct the `CoefficientList` once and store it for future use.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Applying this solution I got a new question.

Comment: According to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50675/using-part-rather-than-extract
One can write 
Part[CoefficientList[poly, Array[x, {3}]], Sequence @@ ({2, 0, 1} + 1)]

Now I am bothering with the general distinction between Extract and Part. Extract takes a list as argument for taking one element from an array, while Part needs several arguments and reads a list in one argument to give out e.g. several rows/columns.

So in general Part is better for "slicing" arrays and can do everything what can be done with Extract. In this special example Extract is shorter?

Comment: Yes, that's really a matter of taste, but I thought `Extract` looks more natural than `Apply[Sequence,{2,0,1}+1]` - I think people should use `Extract` more...

Answer (score 1):

One another possibility might be this:

```
 a*x[1]*x[2] + b*x[1]*x[2]*x[3] /. x[n_] /; n != 1 && n != 2 -> 0

(*   a x[1] x[2]   *)
```